# How can I create a jsprit project in intellijIdea?

Tags: intellij-idea, jsprit

I just simply want to use jsprit in intellij-idea but I can't found any tutorials about jsprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jsprit using maven so it is very simple to use. Just download [source code](https://github.com/graphhopper/jsprit) and open pom.xml file in Intellij-idea.
You can have access all the source code and examples.